# Using android studios scroll View

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hello stack Over Flow community,I am new here and as well to android studios so,sry if i had written anything wrong in advance.I had a doubt regarding scroll view in android and it is as follows

1)As shown in the below image,after using a scroll view in android studios and after the scroll view or horizontal scroll view had filled the screen the remaining component are not visible on the screen and have to be modified or edited only using the component tree window or Xml editor is there a way for me to see the complete view of the elements on the screen by increasing the screen size or else by scrolling them on the screen itself.[Never mind the red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wclmh.png)

Comment: Post your xml code, please

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this will work in your case, but it did wonders on my project.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView">

             //PLACE YOUR ELEMENT/s HERE INSIDE LINEAR_LAYOUT.


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Without your code i cant really test it but i have been using this format for my scrolls and its working so far ^^

Let me know if it worked, maybe i can help you figure that one out